# Mac utility to watch sqlite table and post as JSON?

Tags: json, macos, sqlite, apache-camel

anyone know of:

- a utility that will run on the Apple Mac that will
- listen to changes on a set of tables on a local sqlite table and via
- a configuration mechanism to then
- HTTP post those ongoing changes as JSON requests
- to a remote http or apache camel server?

Thanks, Martin.

Comment: SQLite has no notification mechanism; this would require polling. Can't you do this in the application that changes the DB?

Comment: No, as I have various applications that I want to monitor and I want to do so without the cooperation/modification of the applications that control the data.

Comment: I did note (on http://sqliteexpert.com/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1316061412/0 ) that sqlite has a TRIGGER - can this be used by a utility?

Comment: Getting a notification out of a trigger would require a user-defined function, but those various applications won't be so helpful as to install one for you.

Comment: Comment on irc:

Chunky_Ks: MartinCleaver: as mentioned in the answers to your post... I don't think it's on the cards as sqlite comes in the box


[11:39am] MartinCleaver: Okay - so you agree that to your knowledge -  there's no utility that will attach itself to an SQLite installation, loo at the databases and tables and add a trigger to particular table that calls an external piece of code when CRUD operations occur?

Comment: SQLite is an *embedded* database. There cannot be an external piece of code; all code is internal to the application itself.

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to create such a utility yourself, using the sqlite3_update_hook() function as the starting point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145826/node-js-monitoring-a-database-for-changes looks like a workable approach.